# Rails 4.2 + Nginx + Unicorn - Missing secret_token and secret_key_base after deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, capistrano3

I deployed a Rails 4 app ( using .rbenv ) to a remote Ubuntu server running Ngninx + Unicorn using Capistrano ( staging deployment)

```
E, [2015-08-10T16:53:29.822778 #24117] ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'staging' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
```

Using the capistrano/upload-config , I link the secrets.yml file on the remote server in the current release deployed

```
app/config/
 secrets.staging.yml
 secrets.yml -> /var/www/rails/delayMessage/shared/config/secrets.yml
```

and the /var/www/rails/delayMessage/shared/config/secrets.yml file contains

```
staging:
   secret_key_base: 10c7ed6bccc6d3acb71...
```

Why is the secret_key_base NOT taken into account, and why is this error raised and displayed in the unicorn.stderr.log

UPDATE 1

in unicorn.rb I have the following paths (app and shared ) set ... maybe they are wrong

# Set your full path to application.
   app_dir = File.expand_path('../../', **FILE**)
   shared_dir = File.expand_path('../../../shared/', **FILE**)

Comment: What is `secrets.staging.yml`? is it another file in `app/config`

Comment: I've personally never used Unicorn, so I'm stabbing in the dark. But, I'd confirm that Unicorn is looking at the right directory. For example, since Capistrano points `current` at `releases/[timestamp]`, Unicorn might be pointing at an old version. Alternately, make sure that Unicorn is being restarted after the symlink change so it sees the file (I'd imagine that this is happening correctly).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ... I'll have a look to this Unicorn pointing path... I updated my post with the current paths for app dir and shared dir

 if not using Unicorn , which web server are you using ? ( Passenger or Puma ..)  With previous rails app I used Apache+Passenger, .. I may come back to Nginx+Passenger , it seems the latest Fusion-Passenger version ( called 'raptor' is 5X faster than Unicorn....

Comment: I forgot to require capistrano-rbenv ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but, .rbenv was not on my list. My solution was actually, pretty easy.
First I stopped unicorn (not only restart), I mean, really stop it with the following

```
sudo service unicorn_myapp force-stop
```

And also stopped the Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Then ran the:`RAILS_ENV=environment rake secret` copied the value into the `staging` section in `/deployed_app/shared/config/secrets.yml` and then, restarted all again with

```
sudo service unicorn_myapp start
sudo service nginx start
```

And all is back on track again...

Hope it helps